# Can I sync my Microsoft Account with my Mac?

Tags: macos, sync, exchange, hotmail, microsoft-account

I know it's possible to access my Microsoft Account data (contacts and calendar) using ActiveSync. However, OS X does not support ActiveSync, only Exchange. I was wondering if there is a way to sync this data with my Mac. Thank you!

**EDIT:** It's worth mentioning that the associated address is not a Hotmail or Outlook.com one.